# How to set the system Ruby gems path point to active RVM selected Ruby gems?

Tags: ruby, rvm, sublimetext2

The gems I’ve installed is located inside `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0`. When I try to import the gems, the build result shows that the gems can’t be found.

I’m sure the gems are installed. It’s likely that the text editor I use, Sublime Text 2, is trying to locate the gems inside the default Ruby in OS X.

Is there any way to have any type of text editor to refer the active Ruby version I’ve selected with RVM? Perhaps by modifying .bash_profile or any other methods?

Comment: It is likely that your paths simply are not correct.  You run Sublime Text 2 as the user, so it will take your environment into consideration.  Did you make the changes to your .profile or .bashrc file as suggested by RVM?  Run `rvm notes` and do the needful.

Comment: If I run `which gem` in Terminal, it shows `/Users/SayzLim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/gem`. Just wondering why Sublime Text or Atom can’t discover my gems unless I modify the package to point it to that path.

Comment: If you run which gem in the terminal, I would expect that.  But do you also start sublime text in that same terminal?  If not, then you are using different environments.  You are using RVM, and as you know you can have different Ruby versions running between different terminals.

Answer (score 2):

If you want Sublime to track your ruby and gemset (to build with CMD+B) try this:

1. Open Sublime
2. Sublime text 2 -> Preferences -> Browse packages
3. Open Ruby.sublime-build file in Ruby folder
4. Comment all and add following json:

---

```
{
  "working_dir": "${project_path}",
  "cmd": ["/Users/YOUR HOME FOLDER HERE/.rvm/bin/rvm-auto-ruby", "-Ilib:test",     "$file"],
  "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
  "selector": "source.ruby"
}
```

Comment: I’ve tried this method and it works for Sublime Text. But the other text editor, Atom, doesn’t have this config. I prefer to have all text editors to use use my own ruby gemset.